# How to connect two differents virtual machines (VirtualBox) using IPv6 and gateway

Tags: networking, virtualbox, ipv6, gateway

I am trying to create a virtual machine and clonate it. When I have the copy, I try to connect them using IPv6 but I don't know how I can do it.

This two virtual machines are Ubuntu 14.04.

I need a IPv6 direction and gateway different in each virtual machine, but I don't know how I can obtain it.

I have see a lot of different pages and when I do `ping6 ipv6.google.com` I obtain `connect: Network is unreachable`

I have to say also that I am an amateur user in Ubuntu.

In /etc/network/interfaces I have the next:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface lo inet6 loopback
```

Can anybody help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't ping `ipv6.google.com` then your computer's internet connection probably doesn't support IPv6.  If you go to http://ipv6test.google.com/, that web page will tell you if you have IPv6.

If you just want your virtual machines to be able to access web sites and such with IPv6, then that should be automatic if your computer has IPv6 connectivity.  If you want the virtual machines to be able to talk to each other and the host OS using IPv6, then you will want to create a virtual "host-only" network and connect your virtual machines to it.  To do that I seem to remember that you first create a virtual host-only network in VirtualBox.  Then you add a second virtual network interface card to each virtual machine, and configure the new virtual NIC to connect to the virtual host-only network.  I would recommend getting IPv4 connectivity working first, and then IPv6.  VirtualBox automatically provides a virtual DNS server on a virtual host-only network, so IPv4 connectivity should be automatic.  I'm not sure how it would work on IPv6; you might need to give each virtual machine a static IPv6 address.

Good luck and have fun!

Comment: Finally I have obtained it creating a nat network and enabling ipv6